# Sorting a struct vector

Tags: c++, sorting, struct

I have a big problem..I'm beginner with programming and I try to make a program in C++ for a football league ranking which have to sort the teams depending on their points.

Can someone help with an idea, please?

I created a struct for the teams with the name and the number of points.

How can I sort the teams?P.S. Sorry for my bad English.

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

//I created a struct for the team.

struct team
{
    char name;
    int pct;
}v[20];

int main()
{   int i,sw,aux;

    for(i=1;i<=4;i++)//read the names
    {   
        cout<<"Team "<<i<<endl;
        cin>>v[i].name;
    }

    for(i=1;i<=4;i++)//get the points
    {
        cout<<"Team "<<v[i].name<<" points"<<endl;
        cin>>v[i].pct;
    }

    //bubble sort(not working)
    do
    {
        sw=0;
        for(i=1;i<=4;i++)
        {
            if(v[i].pct<v[i+1].pct)
            aux=v[i].pct;
            v[i].pct=v[i+1].pct;
            v[i+1].pct=aux;
            sw=1;
        }
    }while(sw==1);

    for(i=1;i<=4;i++)
    {
        cout<<v[i].pct<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This code is impossible to read. Do you do it yourself?

Comment: why is impossible?Yes I did.

Comment: You need to swap the whole elements, not just their points. You also need to pay more attention to your array boundaries.

Comment: Uhm the bubble sort is not working..I m searching for another solution.

Comment: The name of your team is stored as (**1**) `char`acter. If thats not your intention you have to make an array of `char`s -- or better use `std::string`.

Comment: Ok, thanks for advice, I modified this on my code.

Comment: You need curly braces if you have more than on statement in a if ... condition. That should fix your bubblesort.

Comment: Thank you a lot! It s working! Now I want to know if it could be another method of sorting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to modify your sort part like this. Assuming you are sorting in desc order.

```
do
{
    sw=0;
    for(i=1;i<4;i++) //< not <= ,because in case of the last element you wont have any other element after it to compare
    {
        if(v[i].pct<v[i+1].pct) // use curly brace as you want all 4 following lines to be executed when its true
        {
            aux=v[i]; //swap entire struct not just one variable
            v[i]=v[i+1];
            v[i+1]=aux;
            sw=1;
        }
    }
}while(sw==1);
```

Also you might need to edit variable type of team name as it can be string.

As you are using C++ there is a one liner function that you can use to sort

```
//#include<algorithm>
//define comparator function
bool cmp(team a, team b)
{
    return a.pct < b.pct;
}

sort(v+1,v+4+1,cmp);
```

Also you can simply write the comparator inside the struct and then use the sort function:

```
struct team
{
    char name;
    int pct;

    bool operator<(team other) const
    {
        return pct > other.pct;
    }
}v[20];
sort(v+1,v+4+1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious about why you include algorithm but do not use any of it. Do you know STL? Since you include algorithm, I guess you may know some simple functions such as swap, sort and copy. They are easy to use, you just need to type one line instead of writing a bubble sort by yourself. Before you use the sort function, you should define which order can take effect on these teams. Just like this:

```
bool compareTeams(const Team &t1, const Team &t2) {
    if (t1.getScore() == t2.getScore()) {
        return t1.getName() < t2.getName();
    }
    else {
        return t1.getScore() < t2.getScore();
    }
}
```

The code above defines a direction we consider to sort the teams, first we sort them by scores, if both of the scores are equal, then we sort them by their names.
Finally We can use the sort function which is ready-made in STL. Now the order we defined can be used. (I guess the array v[] stands for the teams. Am I right?)

```
std::sort(v, v + 20, compareTeams);
```

Comment: my bad i forgot to delete the "#include<algorithm>"..I dont know how sort function works.
And yes, you re right :).